# Best practice for adding complex resources to collections?

Tags: rest, resteasy

Imagine a RESTful service that lets players in a game submit commands to the server.  The object that denotes this command might be called PlayerCommand and look something like:

```
PlayerCommand:
Player player;
Game game;
Command command;
String param1;
...etc.
```

Where Player, Game, and Command are also objects/resources in the service.  When I expose the PlayerCommand resource to allow players to add these, would it be better to just expose a PlayerCommand endpoint, whereby they would post well-formed representations of PlayerCommand resources, i.e. POST /playerCommand?  Or would it be better to let them gloss over some of the complexities of the PlayerCommand object by just putting ids for the dependent resources in the path, e.g. POST /player/{id}/game/{id}/playerCommand?  Seems like the latter would be easier for clients, letting them pass sparser representations of the object (basically just the Command and string params), and then let the server side build the dependent objects based on the IDs.

Basically, when exposing CRUD operations on nested/complex resources, what is the best practice here?

Comment: Is the answer along the lines of not exposing the relationships between entities to end users?  The object in this case is called PlayerCommand because it maps a player to a command in a game.  But that seems like an implementation detail that comes out of the data model; clients should maybe not have to worry about these kinds of mappings and instead limit themselves to the root entities (Player, Game, Command) and let the server side handle the relationships?  This would argue for the 2nd solution I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good way to narrow down the requirements for the design of any resource is to imagine that a GET to its URI will send the exact same representation to the client that a client would PUT to that URI, and vice-versa.

When you POST a PlayerCommand representation, I assume you want a new PlayerCommand resource to be created. When you return such a thing from a GET on a PlayerCommand resource, what do you return? Complete Player, Game, and Command objects embedded in the response? It's better not to; instead, return URI's that point to those resources.

Similary, the POSTed representation should not embed complete representations of the Player, Game, or Command resources; instead, it should contain identifiers for them in the form of URI's. The server can then store the references without having to create new objects for them. A JSON-based example:

```
{"self": "/playerCommand/9803495",
 "player": "/players/84",
 "game": "/games/22980",
 "command": {"base": "/commands/fight",
             "params": ["kick", "Darrel"]
             }
 }
```

Comment: Ahh, I get it.  I hadn't considered having client send URIs.